# Diferença do $apply() e $evalAsync()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Em uma aplicação onde eu tenho carregamento de vários indicadores de um painel de bordo estou utilizando a função $apply() para atualizar os dados desses indicadores porém no console apresenta o erro "Error: [$rootScope:inprog]", alterei a função para a $evalAsync() e o erro não ocorreu mais e aplicação está funcionando normalmente. (Fiz isso na tentativa e erro).

Qual a diferença das funções ?

Comment: Bem, eu sei que o `$digest` do AngularJS não aceita que dois rodem ao mesmo tempo. Quando você coloca `async`, é como se você tivesse "agendando" a evaluação para o pŕoximo cíclo

Comment: Certo, então como eu tenho vários indicadores carregamento ao mesmo tempo o $apply(), não aceita o carregamento de todos os mesmo tempo já o $evalAsync() "agenda" para carregar um por vez ?

Comment: Sim. O `$apply` inclusive deve ser usado quando você tem certeza que, no lugar onde você chama `$apply`, não é coberto por algum cíclo reconhecido pelo Angularjs. Por exemplo, um evento que foi usado com jQuery, ou o `onscroll` do window.

Comment: Muito obrigado, problema já resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que você está tendo problema com o ciclo de atualização dos dados do AngularJS.

O AngularJS configura a maioria dos eventos para poder atualizar/sincronizar valores entre views e controllers. Um exemplo disso é o `input` (falo do evento `oninput`) quando você usa o `ng-model`.

Naturalmente, poderiamos dizer que o AngularJS chama um método de sincronização dos valores a cada vez que esses eventos são disparados.

No caso, creio que esses método sejam o `$apply` ou `$digest`².

Falando especificamente do `$digest`, este como finalidade de chamar todos os `$watchers`¹ (tanto os criados manualmente como os automaticos, como no caso do `ng-model` ou `ng-if`) a cada ação feita pelo usuário.

Esses caras são responsáveis pela mágica do AngularJS, por trás da sincronização dos valores entre View e Controller.

O problema ocorre, geralmente, quando você tenta chamar o método `$digest` ou `$apply` em AngularJS, sem que a chamada dos mesmos não esteja fora desse ciclo do Angular. Pois o Angular automaticamente já é programado para chamá-los. Ao tentar fazer manualmente, isso gera um erro:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'Wallace';
    
    $scope.$digest();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="AppController"> Hello, {{ name }}</div>
</div>
```

O erro que aparece é esse:

> [$rootScope:inprog]

O que parece indicar que o "digest já está sendo executado".

Se você usar `$apply` o erro vai ser exatamente o mesmo.

## Então quando usar `$digest` ou `$apply`?

Use esses caras quando você precisar atualizar os valores do AngularJS em um evento que não está previsto na sincronização automatica do AngularJS.

Por exemplo, se você quiser aplicar uma lógica em AngularJS que depende do evento `onscroll` ou um `mousemove`, você precisaria usar `$apply` ou `$digest` para as que as mudanças sejam processadas, já que o AngularJS não usa os mesmos internamente.

Veja:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'Wallace';
    
    angular.element(window).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    
         $scope.y = e.clientX;
    
         $scope.$digest();
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
   <p>Me o mouse para aparecer a posição</p>
   <div ng-controller="AppController"> A posição do mouse é, {{ y }}</div>
</div>
```

## E o `$evalAsync`?

Por conta do que eu explicar acima é que você teve que usar `$evalAsync`. Pois, como o AngularJs não aceita que dois `$digest` seja executados ao mesmo tempo, você precisa usar os métodos que fazem o `$digest` assincronamente, para forçar o AngularJS a executar essas verificações dos $watchers apenas quando todas as outras chamadas automáticas de `$digest` já tiverem sido processadas.

Os métodos como `$applyAsync` e `$evalAsync` fazem um pequeno "atraso" na chamada de `$digest` para não ocorrer o erro descrito acima.

Veja:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'Wallace';
    
    $scope.$evalAsync(); // Ou '$applyAsync'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="AppController"> Hello, {{ name }}</div>
</div>
```

## Notas

¹ - Quando você usa `ng-if`, `ng-show`, `ng-model`, `ng-class` ou `ng-style` (e qualquer outra coisa que funcione "magicamente" no AngularJS), você está criando um `$watcher` implicitamente. Se você usar o método `$scope.$watch('nome_da_variavel')` você está criando esse `$watcher` manualmente. São esses watchers que o AngularJS executa em cada ciclo de atualização, onde o método `$digest`é chamado.

² - Existe uma pequena diferença entre `$digest` e `$apply`. Fiz uma pergunta sobre isso: [Qual é a diferença entre $digest e $apply?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/342037/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-digest-e-apply)