# Qual é a diferença entre $digest e $apply?

Tags: angularjs

No AngularJS, temos dois métodos que executam os `$watchers` sincronamente: `$digest` e `$apply`.

Eu gostaria de tirar umas dúvidas:

- Qual é a diferença entre eles?
- Quando devo usar um ou outro?

Comment: Essa pergunta é útil. Linkei ela em outra pergunta, para o assunto não ficar muito amplo e fora do foco da resposta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Olá, vou tentar responder essa pergunta usando os conceitos apresentados no livro: AngularJS Up & Running(Shyam Seshadri & Brad Green) e na própria documentação do AngularJS encontrada [aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org).

## AngularJS LifeCycle

---

Primeiramente precisamos entender o que acontece em uma aplicação angularjs quando a mesma é iniciada.

Vamos abstrair toda a parte que navegador ler o que está escrito, assets, html em sua página e vamos pular direto pra parte onde é disparado o evento `document.ready` onde, em uma inicialização não manual, o angularjs irá buscar através da DOM a diretiva `ng-app`, ou utilizando o `angular.bootstrap`, é especificado manualmente onde a(s) aplicação(ões) irá(ão) executar.

Após encontrar o `ng-app`, o angularjs irá iniciar sua "mágica" que é o passo onde o que está no contexto atual é compilado, nesse processo o código definido nas diretivas encontradas é executado, e no final de cada execução é gerado a função `link` das respectivas diretivas.

Com as funções `link` geradas o angularjs as combina com o nosso conhecido escopo, no qual contem as variáveis e conteúdos que é preciso pra gerar nossa UI, com a combinação é gerado a `view`, que é o que o usuário irá ver e interagir. Nesse passo também é instanciado o escopo de cada `controller` e `subcontroller`, e agora que entra a parte que queremos... "É ele que a gente quer...", aqui é onde aparece os nossos amigos:  `watcher` e `listener`, o angularjs irá criar um para cada diretiva que ele encontrou e compilou, assim o nosso querido framework sabe onde encontrar cada coisa e que dado vincular à aquela diretiva.

Beleza, até ai tudo bem... Mas como ele atualiza tudo dinamicamente??

## The Digest Cycle

---

Bom para manter tudo atualizado o *angularjs* usa uma estratégia bem inteligente. Como sabemos o `model` da aplicação não atualiza randomicamente, ele irá mudar em resposta a eventos (requisições, cliques, focos...), logo o angularjs adicionar `watchers` a todos `binds` e `ng-models` e o mesmo pode verificar se os valores contidos naquele escopo difere do que está na UI, e assim pode atualizá-la,

> Mas ele não fica em um *loop* verificando a cada segundo se está tudo
>   atualizado.

Provavelmente qualquer pessoa "normal" se inclinaria para essa ideia, porém obviamente isso é bastante ineficiente.

Como foi falado, o nosso `model` não atualiza randomicamente, porém há certas ações que provavelmente irão modificar ele, logo cada `ng-model` que pode mudar tem o seu respectivo `watcher` e sempre que um evento é disparado o *angularjs* verifica os `watchers` e `bidings` procurando por alterações e fazendo as devidas atualizações necessárias, e essa operação é  chamada de

#### `Digest Cyle`.

O `digest cycle` é o que mantém a UI da nossa aplicação atualizada, e o trabalho que ele faz pode ser explicado nos seguintes passos:

- Sempre que um evento que pode mudar o `model` dispara, o angularjs executa o `digest cycle`.
- O `digest cycle` começa pelo $rootScope e vai verificando cada escopo procurando se existe alguma diference com o que está na UI.
- Se estiver tudo ok no escopo atual ele vai recursivamente até o seu escopo pai verificando todos adjacentes até o fim.
- Se por acaso o AngularJs verificar que um `watcher` reportou uma diferença ele é reiniciado.
- Ele reinicia pois uma alteração pode modificar um o estado de um `watcher` previamente verificado, e assim desencadear varias outras, ele somente para quando todos os `watchers` não reportarem modificação.

> Para prevenir um loop infinito o angularjs reinicia o `digest` apenas
>   10 vezes.

- Todas as atualizações da UI são acumuladas e assim que o ciclo é estabilizado, todas as atualizações são aplicadas.

Imagem para entender melhor todo esse ciclo:

[image: AngularJS Digest Cycle]

**FONTE:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594246/is-there-a-config-option-to-lower-the-amount-of-angularjs-1-x-digest-cycles

### $scope.$apply() e $scope.$digest()

A similaridade entre estes dois métodos é basicamente chamar o que foi explicado anteriormente, **o digest cycle**, a diferença entre eles está baseada nos escopos.

Enquanto o $scope.$apply() força a execução do `digest cycle` direto do $rootScope (Basicamente toda a aplicação atual) o $scope.$digest() força a execução do `digest` apenas em o escopo atual.

Com isso em mente é possível imaginar em quais casos é bom ou não utilizar o $scope.$apply() e $scope.$digest(), a dica é: Em certos casos não precisamos verificar todos os `watchers` de nossa aplicação, apenas o escopo atual.

É preciso tomar cuidado ao utilizar componentes de terceiros que utilizam um `life cycle` diferente da sua aplicação, e nesse caso o mais indicado é utilizar o `$scope.$apply()` pois a atualização deve ser feita através do `$rootScope`, e não apenas no escopo atual com o `$scope.$digest()`.